# Telegram Bot SSL Error

Tags: https, telegram

So I have made a small script on my website for my telegram bot. Only problem is that if I set my URL as webhook for the bot it gives an SSL error.

[image]

Also tried to add an self signed certificate, so has_custom_certificate turned to true, but the same error appeared.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a self-signed certificate for deploying your server over https. If you are using flask you can follow this nice tutorial - https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your certificate.

The error in your getWebHookInfo:

```
"last_error_message":"SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}"
```

Is Telegram saying that it needs the whole certificate chain (it's also called CA Bundle or full chained certificate).

#### How to check your certificate:

You can use the SSL Labs [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) service to check your certificate:

Just pass your URL like the following example, replacing `coderade.github.io` with your host:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=coderade.github.io&hideResults=on&latest

If you see **"Chain issues: Incomplete"** you do not serve a full chained certificate.

#### How to fix:

You need to add all the three needed files (.key, .crt, and .ca-bundle). The Namecheap has very good documentation of how to install an SSL certificate in your site in many different ways, like Apache, Node.js, Nginx and etc. Please, check if you can follow one of the available ways: [Namecheap - How to Install SSL certificates](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/795/69/how-to-install-ssl-certificates)

Anyway, you need to download the full chained certificate for your SSL certificate provider and install this on your webserver.

I don't know which service you are using, but for my example, with [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) I solved adding the [ca-certs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ca-certs) with `ca-bundle` file sent by my SSL Certificate provider (In my case [Namecheap Comodo](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl.aspx)) on my SSL configuration, like the following example:

```
ca_certs = "cert/my-service.ca-bundle"
```

For further information: [@martini](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/770#issuecomment-310484775) answer on this [thread](https://github.com/zammad/zammad/issues/770) and the [FIX: Telegram Webhooks Not Working](https://www.cubewebsites.com/blog/guides/fix-telegram-webhooks-not-working/) post.