# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Working locally but not live

Tags: c#, ssl

I'm making a simple integration with telegram-bot to send messages to a channel.
The code below is working locally, but when I try it live it gives me this error.

**Code**

```
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        string urlString = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{apilToken}/sendMessage?chat_id={destID}&text={text}";
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadString(urlString);
```

**Error**

The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

```
[WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +298
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +106
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address) +32
```

Comment: might want to enable logging as mentioned here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: There are a number of problems that could cause this error. Have you attempted to make the connection manually (e.g. by opening a browser and pointing it at the same location)? The browser may give you more information about the error.

Comment: I have tried to make the connection manually, and it works, that's the strange part.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an SSL certificate, because you need to be using one.
Have a look at this post, does this solve your problem?
[Telegram Bot SSL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106523/telegram-bot-ssl-error)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I'm using an SSL certificate, I installed it into using the Plesk Admin of Goddady, where the app is hosted. Maybe you know if there is something I need to do to specify this in code directly while making a call to telegram?